# Application of Open Mapping Theorem to Resolvent Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let's first recall that an open mapping $T : X \rightarrow Y$ between two metric spaces is such that for any open $A \subset X$, we have $T(A)$ open in $Y$. The open mapping theorem says the following:

**Open mapping theorem:** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. If $T : X \rightarrow Y$ is bounded, linear and surjective, then $T$ is open.

The following passage appeared in the book that I am currently studying:

"*In our present discussion, the bounded inverse theorem (Open mapping theorem) contributes the following. If $T: X \rightarrow X$ is bounded and linear and $X$ is complete, and if for some $\lambda$, the resolvent $R_\lambda(T)$ exists, and is defined on the whole space $X$, then for that $\lambda$ the resolvent is bounded.*"

The passage is claiming that $R_\lambda(T) = (T -\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded for $\lambda$ satisfying the previous conditions. However, I don't understand how both ideas are related.

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit**: The post is answered in the comments.

Comment: The resolvent is the inverse of $T-\lambda I$. They are claiming that if fixing $\lambda$, that inverse exists and is defined on all of $X$, then it is bounded. That is what the open mapping theorem gives you. Being defined on all of $X$ means that $T-\lambda I$ is onto.

Comment: @owl Thanks for the noticing that, indeed, it should be the inverse, I've edited. Oh ok, I didn't knew that being defined on all of $X$ means that it is surjective. But the open mapping theorem concludes that the mapping is open and boundedness is an assumption?

Comment: Wait, wait. Note that here the domain and the co-domain are the same. When they say that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is defined on all of $X$, that $X$ is the co-domain of $T-\lambda I$. It is $T-\lambda I$ that one that is being assumed surjective, when they say that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is defined on all of $X$. The open mapping theorem tell us that $T-\lambda I$ is open, but that is the same as $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ being continuous. Continuous and linear gives us bounded. And, of course, inverse of linear is linear.

Comment: @owl Ohh it started to make sense; We assumed the completeness of $X$, the boundedness and linearity of $T$ and the only property left is the surjectivity. Notice that the continuity and linearity of $T$ ensures the continuity and linearity of $T - \lambda I$. Now, if $R_\lambda(T) = (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is defined on all $X$, it means that the map $T - \lambda I$ is surjective. And so, using the open mapping theorem $T - \lambda I$ is open. Hence the boundedness of $R_\lambda(T)$?

Comment: Yes. that is essentially the argument. Note that we don't know, nor we need to know that $T$ itself is surjective.

Comment: @owl Thank you very much for thelp!